# Why does WordPress site have multiple forward slashes in post category URLs?

Tags: php, wordpress, duplicates

EDIT: I fixed the problem! Thank you to cale_b for pointing me in the right direction. I switched to the 2016 theme and saw that my pagination problem went away, so I knew this was related to my theme. Next, I saved the entire theme folder from the server onto my machine and opened every php file in Notepad++. I then searched for the div that controlled the pagination, in my case it was: div class="pagination group". This showed up in only 1 file, called nav.php, which controlled pagination in my theme. I found this bit of code:

```
echo paginate_links(array(  
  'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',  
  'format' => '/page/%#%',  
  'current' => $current_page,  
  'total' => $total_pages,  
  'prev_text' => __('Prev', 'skoon'),
  'next_text' => __('Next', 'skoon')
));
```

Then I literally just deleted the first forward slash in the 3rd row, next to 'format'. This fixed the issue.

Now that the pagination issue was fixed, I then still had a lot of these pages indexed, so I opened the .htaccess file and addde this little bit of code at the top of the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Now they all redirect to the proper version. I feel like a wizard. haha

woo

---

I am working with a very troublesome WordPress website that has an issue creating multiple versions of the same post category pages with many forward slashes in the URL.

For example:

```
http://example.com/category/treatments//////////
http://example.com/category/treatments//////////////////////////////page/4
```

This issue only happens for Posts (not pages) and has something to do with pagination. All of these multiple versions of my categories are indexed in Google.

I have tried using a plugin called "SEO Redirect" to manually 301 redirect the pages with multiple slashes to the versions with just 1. However, only the ones without a "page/x" at the end work successfully, leaving me with hundreds of versions of the same page accessible. Also, just as a note, my .htaccess file is the default WordPress version, so that is not causing it.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or a simple way to fix it?

Comment: Check your permalink settings.

Comment: @CBroe - they're set to default Post name. In other words, all blog entries are found under a page with URL /category/category-name, but when you click on a blog post on that page it goes to example.com/blog-name

Comment: First, this is not normal WP behavior.  Second, this is either a misconfiguration of your permalinks, your category slugs, or some plugin / theme function causing problems.   Follow WP standard troubleshooting: remove all plugins - does the problem persist? If so, then switch to 2016 theme.  Does problem perist? If so, then it's misconfiguration - maybe your htaccess is wrong?

Comment: @cale_b THANK YOU. I switched to the 2016 theme and saw that the problem was fixed. This helped me realize that the problem is contained within the theme itself. :) I am looking through the theme files now to find where the problem lies. I will update later if I find and fix the issue.